# How can I apply a modifier to selection only?

Tags: modeling

I'm making a cookie cutter model to 3D print, and I want to extrude the upper ring of faces to be wider on the top (or just make it thicker on X/Y axes)
 [image]

I've tried selecting the upper ring and separating it, then applying solidify modifier and later joining both meshes with CTRL+J into one. It looked kind of like I wanted to, but as a side effect I got a few unfixable non-manifold edges so in the end my 'solution' was garbage. Any other ways?

Comment: Bottom line: You can't apply modifiers to selection only. Some do support using *Vertex Groups* for influence though.

Comment: Thanks, that chicken example was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the steps from the thread you've sent me, but I'm lost when it comes to choosing the bevel. I have no idea how to create that sharp curve object. I tried creating a plane just like this and converting it to curve with alt+c but it doesn't work, and when I try to recreate this by using curve tool it all comes out rounded and skewed. Help please :(

Comment: Why doesn't the plane work? Convert the Spline type to *Poly* using the toolbar button

Comment: I figured out how to make my plane a curve, but now when I use the bevel  I get another  [problem](https://imgur.com/TPuYdFi)